# Is there a way to sort the grouping method name in JQgrid?

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, grouping

Is there a way to sort the grouping method name instead of desc and asc (   `groupOrder: ['desc']` ). I have two columns: id and status

```
id     status
1  |   StatusA
2  |   StatusZ
3  |   StatusB
```

I do a grouping after status and I can sort after status, but I wan to sort after id. How can I do that?
I tried this method :

```
groupOrder: ['idName','asc']
```

where idName represents the **id** from

Part of the code :

```
 grouping:true,
        groupingView : {
            groupField : [grup],
            groupSummary : [true],
            groupColumnShow : [true],
            groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
            groupCollapse : false,
            groupOrder: ['asc'] 
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I touched up your block of code a bit. Your `groupField` didn't have your `id` column specified, so I added that:

```
grouping:true,
groupingView : {
    groupField : ['id'],
    groupSummary : [true],
    groupColumnShow : [true],
    groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
    groupCollapse : false,
    groupOrder: ['asc'] 
},
```

Does this help?

Comment: @Chester I just edited mine as well, let me know if that helps